# how can i send the records causing DeserializationException to a DLT while consuming a message from kafka topic using seekToErrorHandler?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE. We are in the process of upgrading the spring boot version but for now, we are using this spring-kafka version.

And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.And I'm using below configuration as specified in the Spring-Kafka documentation.

```java
    // other props
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, AvroDeserializer.class.getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
```

Now, I've implemented my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler by extending SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to capture the send the records causing deserialization exception and send them to DLT.

Now the problem is, when i'm trying to test this logic with 30 messages with alternate messages having the deserialization exception, the list of the handle method is getting all 30 messages instead of getting only 15 messages which are causing the exception. With that said, how can i get the records with exception? Please suggest.

Here is my custom SeekToCurrentErrorHandler code

```java
    @Component
    public class MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler extends SeekToCurrentErrorHandler {

        private final MyDeadLetterRecoverer deadLetterRecoverer;

        @Autowired
        public MySeekToCurrentErrorHandler(MyDeadLetterRecoverer deadLetterRecoverer) {
            super(-1);
            this.deadLetterRecoverer = deadLetterRecoverer;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
            if (thrownException instanceof DeserializationException) {
                //Improve to support multiple records
                DeserializationException deserializationException = (DeserializationException) thrownException;
                deadLetterRecoverer.accept(data.get(0), deserializationException);
            
                ConsumerRecord<?, ?>. consumerRecord = data.get(0);
                sout(consumerRecord.key());
                sout(consumerRecord.value());
            } else {
                //Calling super method to let the 'SeekToCurrentErrorHandler' do what it is actually designed for
                super.handle(thrownException, data, consumer, container);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to pass all the remaining records, so that the STCEH can re-seek all partitions for the records that weren't processed.

After you recover the failed record, use [SeekUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/07d309759919cb492d7f6c3671cc02fc05c7130c/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/SeekUtils.java#L50-L61) to seek the remaining records (remove the one that you have recovered from the list).

Set `recoverable` to `false` so that `doSeeks()` doesn't try to recover the new first record.

```java
    /**
     * Seek records to earliest position, optionally skipping the first.
     * @param records the records.
     * @param consumer the consumer.
     * @param exception the exception
     * @param recoverable true if skipping the first record is allowed.
     * @param skipper function to determine whether or not to skip seeking the first.
     * @param logger a {@link Log} for seek errors.
     * @return true if the failed record was skipped.
     */
    public static boolean doSeeks(List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, Exception exception,
            boolean recoverable, BiPredicate<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> skipper, Log logger) {
```

You won't need all this code when you move to a more recent version (Boot 2.1 and Spring for Apache Kafka 2.2 are no longer supported).

Comment: From this list, how can i identify the records with exception ?

Comment: Assuming you are using a record listener (not a batch listener) - this is implied by the error handler you show, the first record is the only one that failed. We'll hit the next failure the next time around (since `doSeek()` repositions all the unprocessed records).

Comment: i'm trying to use ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord = data.get(0); and send it to the my custom dead letter recoverer accept method which will  send a message to our internal monitoring system and send it to the DLT. The issue with this approach is, 1. it's sending all the records in the list ( 30 messages to DLT in my example) 2. there is huge consumer lag the main topic ( more than 20 in my example). Am i missing anything ?

Comment: On more time, the error handler gets the failed record and the remaining unprocessed records; you should only send the first record to the DLT. Then call `SeekUtils.doSeeks()` which will reposition the remaining records so they will be redelivered on the next poll.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. Now, there is another problem - It seems we are  loosing records if the consumer app restarts while seeking the rest of records. If my observation is correct, how can i handle this?

Comment: Your observation is not correct; the offsets for the records that are seeked were never committed. If you are still having problems, I suggest you start a new question and provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: FYI - Just an observation after debugging the code further. it seems there is a property called 'setAckOnError' which is set to true causing the offset commit. We set it to false and then it's not committing the offset which solved our problem.